# Why does 00.0 cause a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, numbers, syntax-error

This is weird.  This is what happens at the JavaScript console in Chrome (version 42.0.2311.135, 64-bit).

```
> 0
< 0
> 00
< 0
> 0.0
< 0
> 00.0
X Uncaught > SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

Firefox 37.0.2 does the same, although its error message is:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

There's probably some technical explanation regarding the way JavaScript parses numbers, and perhaps it can only happen when tinkering at the console prompt, but it still seems wrong.

Why does it do that?

Comment: And here I thought I have seen all the *WTFs* of the language... And I always enjoy the  moments afterwards.

Comment: This is not an issue that only occurs in the console, `var i = 00.0;` will always throw a SytaxError.

Comment: AFAIK in JS float literal should contain **decimal** integer. Leading zeroes indicates _octal_ integer ([ref.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Integers))

Comment: Good point, @pstenstrm.  I suppose the issue is that the when parsing source code (including stuff typed at the console), Javascript has its strict rules about what is and isn't valid; whereas when dealing with a string (which is the form that _user_ input arrives in), it tries a bit harder to get a result.  So `Number("00.0")` works while `Number(00.0)` does not.

Comment: @ChrisDennis correct, the issue is about parsing source code according the grammar. The rules used by `Number()` function are different from those used by parser (see [ToNumber Applied to the String Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1)).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The expressions `0.0` and `00.0` are parsed differently.

- `0.0` is parsed as a numeric literal <sup>1</sup>
- `00.0` is parsed as:

  - `00` – octal numeric literal <sup>2</sup>
  - `.` – property accessor
  - `0` – identifier name

Your code throws syntax error because `0` is not a valid JavaScript identifier. The following example works since `toString` is a valid identifier:

```
00.toString
```

<sup>1</sup> [Section 7.8.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3) – Leading 0 can be followed by *decimal separator* or *ExponentPart*
<sup>2</sup> [Section B.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1) – Leading 0 can be followed by *OctalDigits*

Comment: Note that 00.0 through 07.0 raise an exception, however 08.0 and 09.0 are perfectly valid due to how the engine doesnt recognize these as octal so instead pareses these as decimal numbers.

Comment: @ChadSchouggins It's curious that digits '8' and '9' are sufficient to tell the parser that it's a decimal rather than octal number, whereas a _decimal_ point is not.  That's what comes of overloading '.' I suppose.  I'd have implemented the parser differently... (were I bright enough to implement a parser at all).

Answer (score 22):

`00` is evaluated as an octal number and `.0` is evaluated as accessing that number's property. But since integers are not allowed to be used as property accessors, the error is thrown.

You get the same error for any other object:

```
'string'.0 // Syntax error: unexpected number
({}).0 // Syntax error: unexpected number
```

You can find related information about property accessors on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: In latest spec the octal literal starts with `0o`. However, due to back compatibility, the old syntax is not likely to be removed from browser implementation.

Comment: Good one. If you find some docs about that feel free to edit the answer to include that info & link - it might be useful for future readers!

Comment: You should probably remove the incorrect part or, probably better, modify / rewrite it to be correct ... and rewriting as opposed to adding (i.e. not having a separate "Edit" block at the top / bottom, but instead rewriting the answer to seamlessly integrate the newly added information) is generally better in terms of long-term value.

Comment: @SalmanA It is the `0` after the dot that is unexpected, not the last `0` in `00`.

Comment: @mflodin the comment was about the earlier version of the answer. I'll remove it.