# How is Javascript trying to interpret this illegal statement?

Tags: javascript

There was a mistake in some Javascript code where the decimal 0.04 was declared as 0.0.4 like the following:

```
var x = 0.0.4;
```

When this was run in Firefox the error given was:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

IE stated:

```
Expected ';'
```

And Chrome stated:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

I understand that 0.0.4 is not a number or a literal but how is Javascript trying to inerpret the statement? Why exactly does it think there is a missing ;  ?

Comment: This depends on how the lexer is implemented. IE, Firefox and Chrome all have their own JavaScript implementation.

Comment: It probably recognizes the first 0.0 as a number, and then gets confused when another dot follows that one. It probably expects a ";" after the second zero because it recognizes the first part as a number.

Answer (score 2):

#### Chrome

Chrome sees the first part of the assignment as a floating point number `0.0`, for which you want to access property at key `0`, which is not allowed in JavaScript (you cannot use dot notation to reference numeric keys). In other words, you can split the assignment to the following equivalent:

```
var x = 0.0
x.0  // Throws unexpected number
```

In comparison, this is valid:

```
var x = 0.0.toString()
```

In my opinion, this is the most logical implementation of the parser with an error that makes most sense.

#### Firefox

Firefox sees the first part of the assignment as the floating point number `0.0`, but gets confused about the `.0` part - it does not recognise this as a property access and instead thinks you want to start a new statement (`.4`, which is a shorthand for `0.4`) - thus it tells you you missed a semicolon, which is used to terminate statements.

It still correctly interprets the statement when you use a valid property accessor (a string):

```
var x = 0.0.toString()
```

Somewhat related is also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368910/why-does-00-0-cause-a-syntax-error) which discusses similar behaviour.

Comment: upvoted because this explains it better than I ever could.. and includes tested examples!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the parser (browser) the way it handles a line of code may be different. My thoughts are that when IE and Firefox see a number they only "expect" a single decimal for a number and then numerical characters after it until either a space or a ';' occurs.

If another character type is encountered the parser would throw an exception that it was looking for the end of the number - hence the `Expected ';'`.

In the realm of how Chrome handled it, it seems like that it can tell it was supposed to be a number, but it was given in an invalid format.

Answer (score 1):

The messages from IE and Firefox make perfect sense. Parse the number part of the statement as `0.0`, perform the assignment `x = 0.0`, then expect an end of statement. If the character following isn't a semi-colon or newline (implicit end of statement), throw an error saying we expect one.

Chrome's is a little more cryptic, but still makes sense with a little thought. It has performed the assignment as with FF and IE (`x = 0.0`) but has interpreted the dot as a dot-operator rather than a decimal. (`x = 0.0.toString()` would be perfectly valid.) Rather than stating what it expected, it's stating what it saw, an "unexpected number", which was the `4`.

It's unclear whether IE and FF first parsed the `.4` as a number or if the unexpected character was simply a dot.

Comment: I think a dot in itself would not cause this because, as you stated, you could still want to continue with a method call or a valid property access. So it was either the number or a combination of the dot with number.